# Scrolling is blocked after router push

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll

Working on a Vuejs project, I am trying to change the page of my PWA using the classic `this.$router.push();` which works perfectly everywhere else but when doing it from a modal included in a component, the pushed page load but I cannot scroll it.

Note that, reloading the page unlock the scrolling and coming from somewhere else to the same page works too. So I gave up looking for the problem from the pushed page.

I tried to hide the modal before calling `push` FROM the modal and it didn't change nothing.
I tried to call `push` from the main page (the one containing the modal-component) after I closed the modal and it didn't change nothing.

I searched a lot and hope that someone already encountered such a problem and found a solution..

Answer (score 0):

As I know modals set this for them-self

```
.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

So with "overflow-x: hidden;" you cannot scroll!
because there is no code I cannot say how solve it but I Think you should force modal be close before route or after routing set

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```